# start intent in activity after http post is finish

Tags: android, post, android-intent

i have a main activity.
from this activity i call a method from another public class.

in the main activity i call this method like this:

```
// Background Task
new Sync.SyncMYSQL().execute();
```

is there an way to start in intent (out of the main activity) if the called method is finish ?

```
public class Sync {

    static class SyncMYSQL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // DO SOMETHING
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) may help you

Comment: you are using AsyncTask on another activity? and want to pass intent to another activity?

Comment: page not found ...

Comment: yes, the Sync.SyncMYSQL is an AsyncTask. and it his task is finish, i would start the intent out of the main activity

Comment: can you show us your SyncMYSQL code?

Comment: SyncMYSQL is now in the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## YES ,

In your asyncTask Class you can override **onPostExecute** method and write your activity start code there

As it executes after doInBackground method :)

Inside your post execute pre-initialize all possible Intents and handle with a switch or if else

Sample

```
public class Sync {

static class SyncMYSQL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int type;
    public SyncMYSQL(int intentType){
       type=intentType;
       }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        return null;
    }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            switch(type){
            case 0: Intent in=new Intent(context,destinationActivity1);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;
            case 1: Intent in=new Intent(context,destinationActivity2);
                    startActivity(in);
                    break;
            }
        }

     }
}
```

call this async task like this

```
new Sync.SyncMYSQL(<integer_value>).execute();
```

Comment: yes that is in way. but the async task will be execute of many other activitys - so the intent have be different each time

Comment: i didnt get your requirement correctly but i assume this is what you looking for and edited my answer, if not please elaborate problem

Answer (score 0):

Use interface for doing this task like.
1> Create interface

```
 public interface AsyncTaskListener {
 public void onHttpResponse(String callResponse);

   public void onError(String error, int pageId);
}
```

2> Than on Async Activity use this

```
AsyncTaskListener listener;

  private void sendResponse(String response) {
      if (listener != null) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
      }
  }
```

And use sendResponse method on AsyncTask OnPost and on response String enter "Success" and After this implement the interface to your first activity and and check if response is "Success" than pass the intent.